# Do subsequent calls to mysqli_fetch_object return the next row?

Tags: php, object, mysqli, fetch

I want to know is every subsequent call to mysqli_fetch_object will return the next row within the result set just as `mysqli_fetch_row`? or why is the while loop needed in the following code:

```
while($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    printf("%s %s\n", $obj->lastname, $obj->age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend looking into the PHP docs on a function to see how it operates. [This doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) should help you digest and understand what it actually does.

### In Summary

In short what you have used as an example will take `$result`, which is a `myqsli_query()` result and create an object for the current row.

The `while` loop is in place to loop through the entire query results. In turn, this creates an object (under the same variable `$obj`) for every row.

One example extracted from the docs:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

### Returning, for example

```
Pueblo (USA)
Arvada (USA)
Cape Coral (USA)
Green Bay (USA)
Santa Clara (USA)
```

**P.S.** If you use Sublime Text, this plugin is marvelous in jumping to the docs: https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-goto-documentation